# How bind dynamic view to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

how can I bind the fields to users controller (asp.net-mvc)?

```
<form method="post" action="/Forms/Users">

 <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
 <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" /> 

  <% for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ %>
     <input type="text" name="Field[<%= i %>]" />
  <% } %>

</form>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

> how can I bind the fields to users controller

To achieve the requirement, you can refer to the following sample code.

*User class*

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Field { get; set; }
}
```

*Index Action*

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new User
    {
        Field = new List<string> {  "Age" ,"Email" }
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

*Index View*

```
@model User

<form method="post" action="/Forms/Users">

    <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
    <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />

    @foreach (var field in Model.Field)
    {
        <input type="text" name="Field" class="form-control" />
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

*Users action of Forms controller*

```
public IActionResult Users(User model)
{
    //code logic here

    return View();
}
```

*Test Result*

[image]